# How to bind images located in isolated storage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, binding, isolatedstorage

I need to bind images located in isolated storage -
I found one answer here and it seems my situation
[Binding image in Isolated Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114153/binding-image-in-isolated-storage)

But then this person has switched to the another solution and used ClientBin for image storage. My pictures will be different all the time.
Now I use images from the server, but I need to save them to the isolated storage and bind to the listBox
code in XAML:

`Image  Width="110" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ThumbURL}"`

code behind:

```
public string ThumbURL
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("http://localhost:3041/Pictures/thumbs/{0}.jpg", _ID);
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnThumbURLChanging(value);
            this._ThumbURL = value;
            this.OnThumbURLChanged();
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ThumbURL");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone advice me of how to do it? I'll be really, really grateful.

Please post some example of the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - nice first question! By the way it's worth getting to know the simple markup you can use (especially for code blocks) so that it's easier for readers to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, I will be, as you mention it is the first question, actually it was first answered question, but second at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download pictures from the web see this previous SO question - [how-can-i-download-and-save-images-from-the-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142169/how-can-i-download-and-save-images-from-the-web).

The difference with binding an image in Isolated Storage is that you have to bind to a BitmapImage object which you initialise from your bound code object. I've renamed your property to "ThumbImage" from "ThumbURL" to show the difference.

So in XAML:

```
Image Width="110" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ThumbImage}"
```

And in your bound object - assuming this picture doesn't change - if it does you'll have to raise the property changed event as appropriate. (code edited to deal with class serialization issue).

```
private string _thumbFileName;
public string ThumbFileName
{
    get
    {
        return _thumbFileName;
    }
    set
    {
        _thumbFileName = value;
        OnNotifyChanged("ThumbFileName");
        OnNotifyChanged("ThumbImage");
    }
}

[IgnoreDataMember]
public BitmapImage ThumbImage 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();                    
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string isoFilename = ThumbFileName;
        var stream = isoStore.OpenFile(isoFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        image.SetSource(stream);
        return image;
    }     
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnNotifyChanged(string propertyChanged)
{
    var eventHander = PropertyChanged;
    if (eventHander != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChanged));
    }
}
```

(Edited to add link to how to download image in the first place)

Comment: Thanks Paul for your response, but I can not use BitmapImage I did try and also ImageSource, but it is also not OK. I have this exeptions: Type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized. 
Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, 
and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If you see "ThumbURL" it is string, I forgot to mention so. I know that is other solution can be, bu now I am wonder if it is possible to have path type of string to the image in the Isolated Storage or, use some other serializable object.

Comment: No, you will need ThumbImage to be of type ImageSource for the binding to work. That exception looks like a side-effect of this change: I take it that your bound class is being serialized in some way (maybe for Tombstoning or storage to IsolatedStorage). You could use both ThumbFileName {get;set} property for your serialization which contains your file name in Iso Storage (replaces ThumbURL). Then mark ThumbImage as not part of serialization. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this "magic" line `[IgnoreDataMember]` makes my code works.
Yes, you right it is due to storage to IsolatedStorage.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts hi i have a doubt in this what is this OnNotifyChanged("ThumbFileName");
        OnNotifyChanged("ThumbImage"); function for ?does i need to call both ? i am new to windows phone application development,and in my app i face the same problem with the bitmap images that mentioned in the question.

Comment: @infoexpert.it hi i have the same problem that u are faced. Please help me with the solution that works for u.I dont understand the line       OnNotifyChanged("ThumbFileName"); 
        OnNotifyChanged("ThumbImage");  .can u please help me?

Comment: @Sujiz sorry, but I has not been working with this subject for two years now, so unfortunately can not help you with this.

Comment: `OnNotifyChanged` is needed to ensure that the XAML page will get the new updated value of both the ThumbFileName and the ThumbFileImage. The concept is called "Data Binding" and is widely used in Microsoft development: this is an example of use of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.aspx for a quick primer.