# Binding albumArt in AlbumCollection to listbox

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, listbox

How can I bind AlbumArt to my listbox?

My code:

```
    <ListBox Name="albumLb" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="albumLb_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" >
                    <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                    <Image Source="{Binding }"/>
                    <StackPanel Width="311">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" Margin="12,-6,12,0"  Foreground="#FFE5CDCD"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And in my code I use:

```
albumLb.ItemsSource = library.Albums;
```

I know that I can get the AlbumArt by library.Albums[int index].getAlbumArt() but I don't know how to bind it into my listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type does `getAlbumArt()` return? If it is simply a path to a file (say in Isolated Storage) then you'll have to write a converter to do the binding. Also, instead of having a function called `getAlbumArt()`, create a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) named `AlbumArt` instead with a public getter, which will allow binding to it. Then you can bind the image using

```
<Image Source="{Binding AlbumArt}" />
```

Next, create a converter (by implementing the [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) interface) that will take the path to a file in Isolated Storage, and load it into a `BitmapImage` which is then returned to the `Image` in your `ListBox` by the converter.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114153/binding-image-in-isolated-storage) has details on how to do this.

---

On the other hand, if you need to download the image from some website, use [`WebClient.OpenReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144211%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(OnImageDownloadCompleted);
wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("www.mywebsite.com/albumart/album1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

void OnImageDownloadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error == null) {
    StreamResourceInfo sri = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result as Stream, null);
    BitmapImage imgsrc = new BitmapImage();
    imgsrc.SetSource(sri.Stream);
  }
}
```

Comment: the GetAlbumArt() return a stream that contains album art image data. I can't bind it like this... You have any suggest?

Comment: @ng_ducnghia No you can't bind it as a stream directly, use a converter to convert it to a `BitmapImage` which can then be bound.

Comment: I use a BitmapImage to bind them to my listbox however it return exception and always got catch. I post new question, please have a look.