# display image in silverlight 4

Tags: wpf, silverlight

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Image/" + txtImage.Text,
                                   UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Why is the image not showing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get this question answered we will need a little more information and context. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: +1: I have added the question they probably meant to ask. URLs in Silverlight have several twists that people need to be aware of. For that reason I am adding back a vote as -2 is a little harsh :)

Answer (score 2):

Your relative URI cannot contain and especially start with `"../"`.

Unless it starts with a `"/"`, or an absolute URL starting with `"http://"`, it is assumed to be in a module.

A URL like `"/images/imagename.jpg"` will find the image located in the `clientbin/images` folder on the hosting website.

Also take a look at my answer here for more info: [Binding image in Isolated Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114153/binding-image-in-isolated-storage/4123378#4123378)